# How to render every face with a unique RGB value?

Tags: rendering, objects, faces

I have a pretty simple scene with a variety of textured cuboids. Additionally to rendering the cuboids with their texture, I would like to create an image where every face is shaded with a unique, single RGB value, such that no RGB is shared between different faces (the value itself is not important). I know that it is possible to use the object ID in the rendering pipeline, but this will give a unique color per object, not per face.

Comment: Have you tried the random pet island input?

Comment: In my blender 2.81 and cycles engine the geometry node doesn't have that output. Can I enable it somehow?

Comment: you didn’t mention geometry nodes before.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant this random per island input, which can be found on the geometry node when creating a material: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html

Is there another random per island option somewhere?

Comment: Maybe I’m naming it wrong, but there is a Geometry node for SHADING that has a random output. Yeah, pretty sure it’s actually not called “random per island.“ PS: no offense with the all caps, just wanted to be sure you knew that the geometry node is not geometry nodes.

Comment: Apparently this was a version problem, in 2.93 I found the random per island option. But I'm still not sure how it can solve the problem efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter edit on your cuboid.  Select all.  Mark seam.  Unwrap.

In UV editor, change pivot point to individual origins, select all, and scale to 0.

In your material, use the UV as a lookup on a scaled up Noise texture, and look at its color.  You'll get a different, unique color for every face.

To get different colors for different objects, perturb your coordinates by an object/random factor.  I'll use vector math/scale to do this, since UV is a vector and object/random is a scalar, but it really doesn't matter how you do it; "add" would work as well.

In the image below, I'm also using an RGB curves node to enhance the contrast.  (A white noise would have been preferable to a noise texture, but in testing, it seemed that there were small imprecisions involved in the lookup that led to non-constant values.)

[image]

Comment: This already looks pretty much exactly like what I'd want, thank you! Since this is a new material and I'm also changing the UV coordinates of faces, how could I render both my original, textured image, and this rgb-per-face image simultaneously? And when I look at the resulting image from this, I actually have over 1500 unique rgb combinations in the image, altough there's only 6 faces visible. I guess it's some kind of interpolation at borders. Can I somehow disable it?

Comment: @jiggy there may be small imprecisions, but any number of rendering options, even rendering with a sample count of greater than 1, are going to mean that in strict image analysis, there exist more colors than faces.  Some info about your end goal would probably help people get what you want.  In terms of rendering some other image, it depends exactly on how you want to combine those, but you should probably be looking into either render layers or additional UV maps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at render layers and additional UV maps.
The end goal is to have ground truth plane segmentation for machine learning, i.e. I want to know which pixel belongs to exactly which plane. I guess a different method would be to directly render a "face/plane-id" into a grayscale image.

Comment: @jiggy well, this isn't going to be a good solution to that problem, which involves more than materials, but rendering settings as well, and doesn't require *perceptually* different colors.  Among other reasons, you're going to get collisions well before you reach 2^24 faces.  You should definitely edit that into your question.  Note that it's basically impossible if you are working with an arbitrary number of objects, even if the sum total of faces is less than the max; consider joining all objects into a single object, at which point you can get guaranteed unique values for each face.